# error: could not find system library 'gobject-2.0' required by the 'gobject-sys' crate

Tags: rust, gtk3

I tried running `cargo run` on my MacBookPro for a GTK3/Rust application and I am getting this error:

```
cargo:warning=`PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_CFLAGS="1" "pkg-config" "--libs" "--cflags" "gobject-2.0" "gobject-2.0 >= 2.56"` did not exit successfully: exit status: 1
  error: could not find system library 'gobject-2.0' required by the 'gobject-sys' crate

  --- stderr
  Package gobject-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gobject-2.0.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  No package 'gobject-2.0' found
  Package gobject-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gobject-2.0.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  No package 'gobject-2.0' found
```

Not sure what occurred here nor how to resolve it.

Comment: you'll need to make sure you have the GTK development package installed. I'm not a Mac user though, so I can't help you any further

Comment: @nielsdg, where do I get the GTK development package? And is that not needed for Linux OS? I have GTK3 with Rust on my Linux machine and I don't recall doing that.

Answer (score -2):

Install the dependency:

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev
```